# Return certain fields in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to return just the arrays that meet my criteria. Here is what i have:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"awardAmount": 20000,
"url": "www.url.com",
"numAwards": 2,
"award": "Faculty Research Grant",
"Type": "faculty",
"Applicants": [
    {
        "preAwards": "NO1",
        "Name": "Omar1",
        "School": "SCSU1",
        "citizenship": "YES1",
        "budget": 1,
        "Advisor": "Dr. DaPonte1",
        "Major": "CSC1",
        "appId": 100,
        "Research": "Test data entry1",
        "Time": "12 months1",
        "URL": "www.url.com",
        "Evaluators": [
            {
                "abstractScore": 11,
                "evalNum": 1,
                "goalsObjectivesScore": 11
            },
            {
                "abstractScore": 22,
                "evalNum": 2,
                "goalsObjectivesScore": 22
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "preAwards": "NO2",
        "citizenship": "YES2",
        "Major": "CSC2",
        "Time": "12 months2",
        "budget": 2,
        "URL": "www.2.com",
        "appId": 200,
        "Advisor": "Dr. DaPonte2",
        "Name": "Omar2",
        "Research": "Test data entry2",
        "School": "SCSU2",
        "url": "www.2.com"
    },
    {
        "preAwards": "NO3",
        "citizenship": "YES3",
        "Major": "CSC3",
        "Time": "12 months3",
        "budget": 3,
        "URL": "www.3.com",
        "appId": 300,
        "Advisor": "Dr. DaPonte3",
        "Name": "Omar3",
        "Research": "Test data entry3",
        "School": "SCSU3",
        "url": "www.3.com",
        "Evaluators": [
            {
                "abstractScore": 454,
                "evalNum": 1,
                "goalsObjectivesScore": 4546
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I want to get back just the applicants that don't have Evaluators fields.

```
{
"_id": 1,
"awardAmount": 20000,
"url": "www.url.com",
"numAwards": 2,
"award": "Faculty Research Grant",
"Type": "faculty",
"Applicants": [
    {
        "preAwards": "NO2",
        "citizenship": "YES2",
        "Major": "CSC2",
        "Time": "12 months2",
        "budget": 2,
        "URL": "www.2.com",
        "appId": 200,
        "Advisor": "Dr. DaPonte2",
        "Name": "Omar2",
        "Research": "Test data entry2",
        "School": "SCSU2",
        "url": "www.2.com"
    }
]
}
```

This is just an example of one document. I want all the Applicants with no Evaluators fields in all documents.

Comment: If your first example is in a variable called `doc`, the following should do it: `[appl for appl in doc['Applicants'] if not 'Evaluators' in appl]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregation with `pymongo`

```
col.aggregate([{"$unwind": "$Applicants"}, {"$match" : {"Applicants.Evaluators": {"$exists": False}}}]))
```

**Output**

```
{'ok': 1.0,
 'result': [{'Applicants': {'Advisor': 'Dr. DaPonte2',
                            'Major': 'CSC2',
                            'Name': 'Omar2',
                            'Research': 'Test data entry2',
                            'School': 'SCSU2',
                            'Time': '12 months2',
                            'URL': 'www.2.com',
                            'appId': 200,
                            'budget': 2,
                            'citizenship': 'YES2',
                            'preAwards': 'NO2',
                            'url': 'www.2.com'},
             'Type': 'faculty',
             '_id': 1,
             'award': 'Faculty Research Grant',
             'awardAmount': 20000,
             'numAwards': 2,
             'url': 'www.url.com'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongo shell you can do this:

```
db.test.find(
{
    Applicants : { $elemMatch : {  "Evaluators" : { $exists : 0 } }}
}, 
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "awardAmount" : 1,
    "url" : 1,
    "numAwards" : 2,
    "award" : 1,
    "Type" : 1,
    'Applicants.$' : 1,         
});
```

One problem is that the above query just return one `Applicants` with no `Evaluators` in it, the valid complete solution will achieve via aggregation

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
   { $match : { Applicants : { $elemMatch : {  "Evaluators" : { $exists : 0 } } } } },
   { $unwind : "$Applicants" },
   { $match : { "Applicants.Evaluators" : { $exists : 0 } } },
   {
       $group : 
       {   
           _id : '$_id', 
           Applicants : { $push : '$Applicants' }, 
           awardAmount : { $first : '$awardAmount' } ,
           url : { $first : '$url' } ,
           numAwards : { $first : '$numAwards' } ,
           award : { $first : '$award' } ,
           Type : { $first : '$Type' } ,
       } 
   }
]  
)
```

Comment: @Michael9; Assume we have 2 member without 'Evaluators', without $group the aggregation will return 2 documents with { Id : 1 } (which have no 'Evaluators'). The sample in question has just one 'Applicants' without 'Evaluators', then the result with or without the will produce same result, but for a complete answer $group will be necessary)

Comment: @Michael9; for example test your solution with {"$exists": true}, it will return 2 docs;

Comment: Yes it does return 2 docs that is why I think $group is not necessary here. Perhaps I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I would suggest using the aggregation pipeline to `$unwind` the documents on your 'Applicants' field. You can then filter the resulting documents using `$match` to remove the documents where 'Evaluators' exist then `$group` them back together using `$first` and `$push`. Hope this is of some help.